# (Iron)Python formatting issue with modulo operator & "negative zero"

Tags: python, string-formatting, ironpython, modulo

Today i noticed following issue on IronPython2.7:

When formatting a format_string like so, i get a "negativ zero". I get the same result if i use Python2.7 or Python3.4 instead of IronPython.

```
>>> "%.2f" % -0.004
'-0.00'
```

Then i realized, that i can get rid of the negativ zero by passing two arguments to the format string like so:

```
>>> "%s%.2f" % ('x', -0.004)
'x0.00'
```

'x' is a random character. So, i format another string before the float value and the minus disappears. That does not work with Python2.7 and Python3.4 though, where i get:

```
>>> "%s%.2f" % ('x', -0.004)
'x-0.00'
```

Does anybody know what's going on here?

What is the purpose of the formatted "negativ zero" at all?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in IronPython. It's supposed to follow the CPython reference implementation wherever feasible.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware, but negative zero is a perfectly valid float value: `-0.0`. It's distinct from (but equal to) positive zero. No idea why IronPython makes the minus sign disappear with there's another value in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

(edited to take @MarkDikinson comment into account)

You can format the number first, then doing the `printf`-like formatting:

```
"%.2f" % (round(-0.004, 2)+0)
```

The `+0` is there to remove the negative zero sign.

`round` can also take a `ndigits` argument, to specify how
many digits you need for the rounding of the number itself *(not talking about display, which is handled by `"%.2f"`)*.

Comment: Why use NumPy's `around` instead of Python's built-in `round` function? (And you probably want to round to 2 decimal places ...)

Comment: @MarkDickinson you're right ! I use numpy all the time at work but there is a standard round too ;)

Comment: @mguijarr installing numpy for ironpython could be problematic

Comment: @Odomontois indeed, that's why I simply removed numpy from my answer, I just originally forgot about standard `round` function ;)